# Macro with conditions to get a NSString

Tags: ios, macros, nsstring, conditional-statements

I'm trying to make a macro that will be a string depending on some conditions.
The goal is to detect on what type of device the app is running (iPhone, iPhone retina, iPad or iPad retina).

Here is my attempt :

```
#define BEST_PICTURE_SIZE_KEY \
if([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]==2.0) \
    (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)?@"LARGE":@"HUGE" \
else \
    (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)?@"BIG":@"LARGE"
```

But when I try to use it I get errors :

```
if([lc_classified.photo objectForKey:BEST_PICTURE_SIZE_KEY])
[lc_urlArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",appdelegate.initObject.imgPrefix,[lc_classified.photo objectForKey:BEST_PICTURE_SIZE_KEY]]];
```

Any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try reformating it like that :

```
#define BEST_PICTURE_SIZE_KEY \
(([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]==2.0) ? \
(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)?@"LARGE":@"HUGE" \
: \
(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)?@"BIG":@"LARGE")
```

It seems to work.

Comment: Yes, thanks. It seems that conditions have to be inline only.